# Keeping text vertical alignement between two columns

Tags: text, typography, alignment, scribus

I have a main text spread across two columns. In this text I have a quotation block, with a different paragraph style (lower font size, indentation). This quotation block starts at the bottom of the first column, and ends at the top of the second column. Because of this, when the main text resumes in the default style, it is not vertically aligned with the main text of the first column:

[image]

Is there a way around this? I work with the latest development branch of Scribus (1.5.8).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scribus, but I would suggest that you try searching for 'baseline grid' or 'snap to baseline'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Align to Baseline Grid* option in the *Properties > Text* dialog. I'm not sure about more recent development versions, but I suppose it will be similar.

An example showing three linked text boxes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's the setting I was looking for!